# Making ng-options dynamic in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I have an array as follows:

```
$scope.age = 2;
$scope.people = [{name:"Sam",age:2},{name:"Pam",age:3},{name:"Ham",age:4}]
```

I want the `ng-options` to be dynamic i.e.,
If the age is 2 then show all objects of people in ng-options. 
If the age is 1 then show object with name as "Sam".

`$scope.age` can have value either 1 or 2.

How can I do this in AngularJS without writing different block of select statements?

Comment: What is the logic of 'if age is 2, return Pam and Ham, else if age is 1, return Sam'

Comment: You can check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the select to the result of a function:

```
<select ng-options="person as person for person in getPersons()">
</select>
```

Then setup your scope like this:

```
$scope.age = 2;
$scope.people = [{name:"Sam",age:2},{name:"Pam",age:3},{name:"Ham",age:4}]
$scope.getPersons = function() {
    if ($scope.age = 1)
        return $scope.people.filter(function(item) {
            item.name == "Sam";
        });
    else
        return $scope.people;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-options` directive can also parse [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), so you can do something like this:

```
<select ng-options="person as person for person in people | filter:{age:age}">
</select>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez4pvszs/)

Comment: How can this work, please see the conditions and what objects I need to display in ng-options

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) as below with a custom function.

**Working sample**: (*type 1 or 2 in the textbox below to test this*)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.age = 2;
  $scope.people = [{name:"Sam",age:2},{name:"Pam",age:3},{name:"Ham",age:4}];
  $scope.filterPeople = function(person) {
     return $scope.age === 2 || person.name === "Sam";
  };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  Age: <input type="text" ng-model="age" />
  <select ng-options="person as person.name for person in people | filter:filterPeople" ng-model="selected">
  </select>
</div>
```